# Post type gives 404 unless logged in

Tags: posts, permalinks, wp-admin, 404-error

My custom post type gives a 404 (slug translated by WMPL), unless I login to the admin.
Then it works again for several days (it seems), just to become 404 again.
Login in again (without doining anything further) makes it magically work again.

I tried rebuilding the permalinks, and clearing the cache (and rebuilding) afterwards, but this does not solve the issue.

What does the WP-admin do to the permalinks after login in?

Comment: It shouldn't do anything. Does the issue occur when WPML is deactivated?